# Outlook 2007: Could not install the custom actions. The object could not be found

Tags: outlook, outlook-2007

I have a user who is getting a warning message dialog every time he opens a message window in Outlook 2007:

> Could not install the custom actions.  The object could not be found.

Clicking OK dismisses the dialog and everything appears to work fine.

Comment: +1. This seems like a perfectly reasonable sysadmin question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.  It was caused by the Microsoft LiveMeeting add-in.  It created a message form in the `C:\Users\[current user]\AppData\local\Microsoft\FORMS` folder that was corrupted.  Deleted it and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is also likely related to a WebEx plug-in.  We've been trying to track this error down with the frequent occurrence with our customer.  However, we are integrating Live Meeting currently, and the same error returns for one of our users.  I wonder if Live Meeting uses forms similar to the WebEx Outlook Integration tool 2.2 before they changed it to a plug-in on their 3.2 version.

Something to think about...